# Stop setInterval function set inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this simple useEffect code. When the user logged in to the application every 2 minutes I will dispatch an action which is an API call, and I need to stop this interval once a user is logged out. Still, the current code even runs after the user is logged out, what shall I do to prevent this interval when the user logs out.

I am using the value from the localStorage to determine whether the user is logged in or not.

```
 const intervalId = useRef(null)
    useEffect(() => {
    const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("isUserLoggedIn")  //(true or false)
    intervalId.current = setInterval(() => {
    dispatch(refreshUserToken());
    if(isLoggedIn === false){
    clearInterval(intervalId.current)
    }
    },1000*60*2)

return () => {
clearInterval(intervalId.current)
}
    },[])
```

Is there any way to resolve my issue?
Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: If you use Axios for HTTP requests, you could add this functionality to the interceptor object. That mean if the request happens after x seconds it would resolve the new token before actually making the request you want.

Answer (score 2):

You should be adding the line where you get that value from `localStorage` inside the interval, if you want the updated value. Also, `localStorage` would gives you a string instead of a boolean, either you parse it, or you change your if statement.  Try with this:

```
const intervalId = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
  intervalId.current = setInterval(() => {
    const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("isUserLoggedIn"); //(true or false)
    if (isLoggedIn === "false") {
      clearInterval(intervalId.current);
      return;
    }
    dispatch(refreshUserToken());
  }, 1000 * 60 * 2);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId.current);
  };
}, []);
```

You could use an event instead of a setInterval. As an example, change the code where you are setting the localStorage to this:

```
localStorage.setItem("isUserLoggedIn", true); // or false depending on the context
window.dispatchEvent(new Event("storage")); // you notice that there is a change
```

You change your `useEffect` to this:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const listenStorageChange = () => {
       const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem("isUserLoggedIn");
       console.log(isLoggedIn);
       // do your logic here
    };
    window.addEventListener("storage", listenStorageChange);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("storage", listenStorageChange);
},[])
```

Comment: Thanks bud, but still, the setInterval is running even if the local storage value becomes false

Comment: Are you able to log `isLoggedIn` in the `setInterval` before the if statement?

Comment: Actually, when I logged in, I can see the value still remain false even after the user logged in. seems like the local storage value is not updating here? is there any other way to achieve this

Comment: And in the devtools, the value is being updated?

Comment: Anyway, I just pasted another possible way to see the problem. Give it a shot please.

Comment: Thanks for the efforts dude, I actually removed local storage and instead used redux to store that value.

Answer (score 1):

The keys and the values stored with localStorage are always in the UTF-16 string format. As with objects, integer keys and booleans are automatically converted to strings.

So you have to call like this:

```js
if(isLoggedIn === 'false'){
    clearInterval(intervalId.current)
}
```

Check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but still, the setInterval is running even if the local storage value becomes false